# Can jam be made from frozen berries?

Tags: fruit, frozen, jam, blueberries, raspberries

During summer months, I love buying fresh raspberries and blueberries. I often don't manage to work through the whole punnet, so I freeze the last few berries before they go off. Now the berries have piled up and I'm not so sure if it would work to make Jam with them?

Comment: A more general, otherwise identical Q/A: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/60363/can-frozen-peaches-be-made-into-jam-or-other-things/

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Freezing can change the texture of the berries, but if you're cooking them down to make jam with, it shouldn't matter.  Some recipes using frozen berries suggest preparing the fruit for this purpose ([adding lemon or crushing strawberries](http://www.theselfsufficienthomeacre.com/2013/11/how-to-make-jam-from-frozen-fruit.html)), others start with [pre-frozen fruit](http://jamiecooksitup.net/2012/10/homemade-jam-from-frozen-raspberries-blueberries-and-marionberries/) that had no special jam-related preparation.

Comment: Absolutely. My homegrown berries don't ripen all at once so I save them in the freezer and make jam from them almost every year.